# Car won't start help please

Tags: chrysler, no-crank-no-start, sebring

It's a 2003 Chrysler Sebring.

I turn the key and there's no sound and the radio doesn't work. I know that might or might not be important but I added it anyways.

When I turn the key the dash lights come on and the headlights work and the fan will come on.

I replaced the ignition switch and the battery and the ignition relay and still have nothing.

I don't want to replace the starter unless I have to but I'm running out of idea of what it could be.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! When you turn the key you get absolutely no sound (no clicking, no nothing)? Do the lights turn out (radio/dash)? Is there a dash light which looks like a key (maybe blinking)?

Comment: The thing to check is whether or not the starter is getting 12V power when the key is turned.  My guess is no, it's not.  There is a very direct path for 12V from the battery to the starter.  Trace that until you find the problem.

Comment: Possible immobiliser issue?  Is there anything indicating that the immobiliser is active?